# Cannot send HTTP request while debugging

Tags: nativescript

My applications works fine when i run it by **tns run ios**, but when i try to debug it with **tns debug ios** it doesn't work well.

When i do an HTTP request to my back-end it won't be received in the back-end and an error wil occur.

> "this.dispatchMessage is not a function. (In 'this.dispatchMessage', 'this.dispatchMessage' is undefined)"

This is the code i am using:

```
http.request({
        url: config.baseUrl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        content: data
    }).then(function (response) {
        // Success
    }, function (e) {
        // error occur
    });
```

Comment: The network tab under NativeScript Inspector is currently under development and some network related options may also cause this behaviour.

Comment: @ Nick Iliev After upgrading tns-core-modules to 2.0.0 fetch stopped working for me while debugging. I get "Network request failed" on any request. I guess most of devs use debugging mode most of time. And you are saying that http request don't work in this mode? One of the most important functionalities just don't work? Any workaround??? Please don't suggest downgrade to 1.7.1 (requests do work when I downgrade back) since I need awfully x-index support which is not working in 1.7.1!

Comment: You could start the debugger after the network requests, this is the only way i can debug at this moment. Use 'tns debug ios --start'

Comment: indeed fetch module was not working on 2.0.0 and was fixed with v.2.0.1